# How to merge React App and Express App to deploy on single project?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I recently create Express and MongoDB API and after that, I connect that API to my React Application successfully and which is running well. But one situation occurring during deployment now I need to deploy both projects separately means I need two hosting plan for them. So, I want that both project running on the same host. Is it possible? and How?

Answer (score 1):

A build of any React application creates (unless webpack-dev-server is used to compile it) the output which consists of static files: script bundles and .html file(s) that reference the bundles in `<script>` tag.

Those files can and should be copied to Express in *production* build. Then you have one server on one host. When React application runs inside a client (e.g. browser) it gets everything including .html files, script bundles, API responses from the single source: Express backend/server. Which by the way excludes any possibility of getting CORS issues so many people are asking about here on SO.

Example, e.g. a boilerplate [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) that demonstrates all that.
If you execute commands:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react.git
cd crisp-react
yarn install && yarn start:prod
```

and then point your browser to `localhost:3000`, you will have React app running inside your browser and it got everything from one single Express backend.

[crisp-react](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) has two subdirectories: `client` with React client app and `server` with Express backend. The build command copies the build artifacts from one subdirectory to another. So you can even rename or delete the `client` subdirectory after a build, it won't affect the Express backend.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can let your express server serve the build/dist folder from your React/Frontend/Client and serve it in express or make it build directly into your express folder. Works with webpack as well. Something like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

//The path to your react app build folder
app.use(express.static("../app/dist"));
```